# How does attribute assignment in R break down in terms of the language grammar?

Tags: r, grammar, assignment-operator, language-implementation

#### Problem

In R, you can assign an attribute like so:

```
attr(x, "foo") <- "bar"
```

I get what this does, but I'm trying to understand how this statement breaks down into more fundamental pieces of the R language.

#### Thoughts

While `attr` is a function, it appears to also be a part of the fundamental language grammar, since you cannot do this:

```
t = attr
t(x, "bar") <- "baz" # gives an error
```

The most similar syntax I can think of is in PHP, where you can assign by "calling" the `list` "function" like this:

```
list($a, $b) = array(1, 2);
```

I understand the above line to have the following grammar:

```
list_assignment:
    list(<var>...) = <expression>;
```

It would seem to make sense that in R, the grammar is defined similarly:

```
attr_assignment:
    attr(<var>, <expression>) <- <expression>;
```

But you can also write this:

```
x = `attr<-`(x, "bar", "baz")
```

Which seems that it would require one of the following:

- Special support for `` `attr<-`(<var>, <expr>, <expr>) `` in the grammar
- A real function named `attr<-` which does the same as `attr(...) <-` under the hood

#### Summary

How should this `attr` assignment should be thought about in terms of simpler language elements? What about `` `attr<-` ``? Additionally, how are these implemented within the R parser?

Comment: `attr<-` is a separate function. There are numerous such "assignment" functions defined in R. They are all implemented as separate functions, so if you ever want both `foo()` and `foo() <- bar` to work you have to write two functions. I can't tell you the details of how the parser recognizes them, but I know that it does.

Comment: @joran Thanks to your comment I found a section in Hadley Wickham's Advanced R that explains what's going on. It seems that the R language converts any expression like `blah(...) <- <expr>` into a call to \`blah<-\`(<expr>), so the former is just syntactic sugar for the latter. Feel free to post an answer. https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#replacement-functions

Comment: @ChrisMiddleton, you can also find this described in the documents that come with R, hidden in section 3.4.4 of the R Language Definition.